# override translation with silverstripe 3.x (3.1 from GitHub)

Tags: content-management-system, silverstripe

I have a folder structure where mysite & themes life in one folder called app. Now I try to override some translations with app/lang/de.yml.

In general app is...

```
After: 'framework/*','cms/*'
```

...but it seams i18n order having it's own rueleset which I'm not able to make them work or to understand :-(

I went with smtg like the following in app/lang/_i18n.yml. After or Before both do not override the translation.

```
---
Name: customi18n
After: 'defaulti18n'
---
i18n:
  module_priority:
    - app
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have to specify the order of your translation files as your're just overriding the default. I just placed my translation files in /mysite/lang/ (de.yml,en.yml) and gave them the following structure and flushed the config via `?flush=all`

```
de:
  your.translation.KEY: 'foo bar'
```

Comment: thank you Jörn for answering and sorry for my delay. I've now set up a test-instance with 3.0.6 and then updated it to 3.1.x-dev. With 3.0.6 it worked as you describe but not with 3.1. Unfortunately I still don't have a clue how to solve it :-(

Comment: I'm running 3.1.x-dev as well. At the end i moved most of my translation-files to /themes/my-theme/lang/en|de.yml to override the tags defined within the templates.

Another way to get the files at the right position is to run silverstripes [TextCollector-Task](http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/topics/i18n#collecting-text). You can use the generated files as a starting point for your translations.

Comment: https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/pull/2295#issuecomment-24987819